# Problem uploading and viewing PDF in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

```
\[DocumentManager\] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=\_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
```

I am getting the above error after I choose the file. I had this problem in my main app, so I made a dummy one in case there was some problem with my original code, but I still end up getting the same error.

## Following is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isPickerPresented = false
@State private var selectedURL: URL?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let url = selectedURL {
                PDFKitRepresentedView(url: url)
            } else {
                Text("No PDF selected")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                self.isPickerPresented = true
            }) {
                Text("Choose File")
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isPickerPresented) {
            DocumentPickerViewControllerRepresentable() { url in
                self.selectedURL = url
            }
        }
    }

}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
let url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        uiView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    }

}

struct DocumentPickerViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
private let onPick: (URL) -\> Void

    init(onPick: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
        self.onPick = onPick
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.pdf])
        documentPickerController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return documentPickerController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        private let parent: DocumentPickerViewControllerRepresentable
        
        init(_ parent: DocumentPickerViewControllerRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            guard let url = urls.first else { return }
            parent.onPick(url)
        }
    }

}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
ContentView()
}
}
```

I tried making an uploader using Swift UI directly, but since that didn't work, I ended up using UIViewControllerRepresentable(), but was greeted with the same error. I tried finding solutions online but most of them are either outdated or gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Document Picker

```
struct DocumentPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedPDF: PDFDocument?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        @Binding var selectedPDF: PDFDocument?

        init(selectedPDF: Binding<PDFDocument?>) {
            _selectedPDF = selectedPDF
        }

        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            if let pickedURL = urls.first {
                let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: pickedURL)
                selectedPDF = pdfDocument
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(selectedPDF: $selectedPDF)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPickerView>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType.pdf], asCopy: true)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPickerView>) {
        // No update needed
    }
}
```

Using kit uiview

```
class PDFKitView: UIView {
    
    private lazy var pdfView: PDFView = {
        let view = PDFView()
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        view.autoScales = true
        return view
    }()
    
    func loadPDF(from docuemtn: PDFDocument) {
        pdfView.document = docuemtn
        addSubview(pdfView)
    }
}
```

UIViewRepresentable then

```
struct PDFViewViewer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var doc: PDFDocument
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFKitView {
        let pdfView = PDFKitView()
        pdfView.loadPDF(from: doc)
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFKitView, context: Context) {}
}
```

upload and view the pdf

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingDocumentPicker = false
    @State private var selectedPDF: PDFDocument?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Select PDF") {
                isShowingDocumentPicker = true
            }
            .padding()
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDocumentPicker) {
                DocumentPickerView(selectedPDF: $selectedPDF)
            }

            if let pdfDocument = selectedPDF {
                PDFViewViewer(doc: pdfDocument)
            } else {
                Text("No PDF selected")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import MobileCoreServices // Required for UTType
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
import UIKit
```